# How many ways are there for W women and M men to sit on N chairs, if no man can sit next to woman?

Tags: combinatorics

So, we have:

```
W - count of women
M - count of men
N - count of chairs standing in a row (N > M + W)
```

Each person sits on her chair, and only two men or two women can sit on adjacent chairs. How many possibilities are there for them to sit?

Comment: If there are e.g. too many men relative to women, there would be no way to avoid adjacent chairs.

Comment: @coffeemath  I think that's covered by $N>M+W$, no?  After all, you can just put all the men on the left and all the women on the right.

Comment: @lulu But then there would be a man next to a woman (where the two groups meet).

Comment: @coffeemath: It is allowed to have a man and a woman with an empty chair between them.

Comment: @coffeemath  Since $N>M+W$ we have a category $E$ of empty chairs.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes I didn't read carefully, there will be empty chairs.

Comment: @lulu For $M=W=1$ and $N < 4$ it is $\frac{(N-2)!2}{(N-2-w)!}$

And for $N > 3$ it is  $\frac{(N-2)!2}{(N-2-W)!} +\frac{(N-2)(N-3)!}{(N-3-W)!}  $ right ?

Comment: @ritwiksinha  That seems complex.  Given $M=1=W$, if we ignore the condition there are $N (N-1)$ ways to place our two people.  If we consider the block $MW$ we see there are $N-1$ ways to place it (i.e. the man can sit in $N-1$ spots).  Similarly there are $N-1$ ways to place the block $WM$.  Hence in this case the answer is $N(N-1)-2(N-1)=(N-2)(N-1)$.

Comment: @lulu Do you have an answer for M, W where M and W is not a trival case above ?

Comment: @ritwiksinha  I do not have an answer I like, no.  I get a mess involving partitions of $M,W$.  Does not appear to simplify...rather I have not yet found a useful simplification.

Comment: @lulu i think i have a answer if $W = 1$.

Comment: @ritwiksinha that case should not be hard.  Either the woman goes first or last (both easy) or she's in the middle in which case replace her with the block $EWE$.  Thus it is $2\times \binom {N-2}M+(N-2)\times \binom {N-3}M$.

Comment: Thank You all for Your replies. @ritwiksinha there are many 'similar' questions on internet, but this one is what I came up with myself and is surely what I mean. I tired to solve it on my own, but failed, so posted here. It is even possible that this problem does not have an analytical solution, then I would appreciate a proof of that

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong, i worked on this on question for one or two hour, I am sure somebody will get a solution to this question or a proof that there is no solution to it. Lets see who does it.

Comment: Is there some problem with my answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We shall be using both [Theorem 1 and Theorem 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) of stars and bars

Let us put number of empty chairs as $E = N-(W+M)$, with $W,M,E >0$

These $E$ chairs act as *bars* (dividers) in the stars and bars approach, making $(E+1)$ boxes in which to put women and men, treated as just *categories* for the moment.

We can place the women in $A$ boxes, $1\le A \le E$, using Theorem $1$ in $\binom{W-1}{A-1}$ ways,
choosing the $A$ boxes in $\binom{E+1}{A}$ ways

$(E+1-A)$ boxes now remain, and we can place the men using Theorem $2$ in $\binom{M+E-A}{E-A}$ ways

If each person is treated as distinct, we shall, of course, have to multiply by $W!M!$

Putting the pieces together, # of ways = $$W!M!\sum_{A=1}^E\binom{E+1}{A}\binom{W-1}{A-1}\binom{M+E-A}{E-A}$$

---

**ADDED NOTE**

I have put the condition $W,M,E>0$ to exclude trivialities.

Comment: The analysis is right, but there are typos. First, the $N$ in the sum should be an $E$, from the explanation. Second, the upper limit of the sum should be $E+1$. Third, the middle binomial coefficient within the sum should be $W+A-1\choose A-1$. I think that's it. If so, the answer is $$W!M!\sum_{A=1}^{E+1}\binom{E+1}{A}\binom{W+A-1}{A-1}\binom{M+E-A}{E-A}$$, which seems to address your observations.

Comment: Ah, not quite. The middle binomial coefficient was correct. Women are placed into exactly $A$ groups with at least one woman in each group. But the answer with this correction is not quite right, because the stars-and-bars formula for partitioning $n$ into $k$ parts only apply when $n$ and $k$ are *positive*. So perhaps we could write the answer as $W!M!\sum_{A=1}^{E+1}\binom{E+1}{A}{\binom{W-1}{A-1}}^*{\binom{M+E-A}{E-A}}^o$ where the “starred” and “circled” binomial coefficients mean stars-and-bars problem answers for positive parts (*) and nonnegative parts ($\circ$)

Comment: @SteveKass: If the upper limit is $E+1$, there will be no boxes left for men. And Theorem $1$ and $2$ (as given by Wiki) both are treated under stars and bars combinatorics.

Comment: If there are 0 men, the $A=E+1$ term is important. Let $W=2, M=0, N=3$. If you don’t let $A$ go to $E+1=2$, you’ll only count arrangements with the women together (in the same “box”); you’ll miss arrangements with an empty chair between the women. As for stars-and-bars, I’m not sure what you’re saying. The Theorems in Wikipedia are correct, but they only apply when $n$ and $k$ are positive. Let $M=3, W=0, N=5$ and look at the $A=1$ term. It uses $-1\choose0$ for the number of ways to put 0 women into 1 group with no empty group. But there are no ways, yet $-1\choose0=1$.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing. The sum has to start at $A=0$, not $A=1$. If there are no women, then there are no ways to put them into a positive number of “boxes”, and you’ll miss arrangements with no empty chairs at either end of the row of chairs and men.

Comment: Correcting an earlier comment, the expression $-1\choose 0=1$ should have read ${-1\choose0}=1$.

Comment: I have put the condition $W,M,E >0$ to exclude trivialities.

Comment: Thanks, glad you like it ! @user84413

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(N,M,W)$ be the answer.  We have boundary conditions
$$ \eqalign{F(N,0,W) &= {N \choose W} \ \text{for}\ W \le N\cr
            F(N,M,0) &= {N \choose M} \ \text{for}\ M \le N\cr
            F(N,M,W) &= 0 \ \text{for}\ M, W > 0,\; N \le M+W\cr
           }$$
Otherwise consider the possibilities for the first empty chair.
If the first empty chair is in position $j+1$, then the first $j$ positions are either all men or all women.
$$ F(N,M,W) = F(N-1,M,W) + \sum_{j=1}^{M} F(N-j-1, M-j,W) + \sum_{j=1}^{W} F(N-j-1,M,W-j)$$

Hmm.  It looks like $F(2i+n,i,i)$ is the coordination sequence for the lattice $A_n$: see e.g. [OEIS sequence A005901](https://oeis.org/A005901). This has generating function

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}^2 z^k/(1-z)^n = P_n\left( \dfrac{1+z}{1-z}\right) $$ 
where $P_n$ is the $n$'th Legendre polynomial.

And more generally, $F(n+2i+j,i+j,j)$ (for fixed $n$ and $j\ge 0$) seems to have generating function $$ \sum_{k=0}^n {n-j \choose k}{n+j \choose n-k} z^k/(1-z)^n $$